# Best way to test search method in model with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model Building, and buildings has many people. Also building have search method with many params. I want to test this method.

One of idea, use a test db with many data.

Another idea, use Factory, but for good testing only one params of search method i need around 3 Building and around 10 people.

What is the best way to test such method?

Comment: The problem description is a bit vague ("method with many params"). Could you be more specific?

Comment: for example, find all buildings where more than 3 and less when 10 people, or all buildings where live any of people(array of people)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations). There is an example of generating data for `has_many`.